# Using variables in a mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want to use a variable i have declared in a trigger.This is the trigger

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER le_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON inbox
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

declare last_inserted_number varchar(100);
declare last_inserted_message varchar(100);

set last_inserted_number  = NEW.in_number;
set last_inserted_message = NEW.in_message;

insert into transactions (message,tel) values(@last_inserted_message,@last_inserted_number);
   END$$
delimiter ;
```

but it can't seem to get the new values i want to fetch from the table inbox.How do i use the variables?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `@` from the variables

```
insert into transactions (message,tel) 
values(last_inserted_message, last_inserted_number);
```

Variables with and without `@` are 2 different kind of variables.